# Colors 0-15 Assembly

Tags: assembly, fasm

Good night,

I'm trying to do a project with assembly(FASM), where i need to do some triangles and put 2 colors from 0 to 15 (ask the number to the human using the program)

i got this to "read" the values:

```
    mov ah, 40h
    mov bx, 1
    mov cx, 22
    mov dx, color1msg
    int 21h

    mov ah, 3Fh
    mov bx, 0
    mov cx, 1
    mov dx, color1
    int 21h

    mov ah, 3Fh
   mov bx, 0
   mov cx, 2
   mov dx, crlf
   int 21h

   mov ah, 40h
   mov bx, 1
   mov cx, 1
   mov dx, paragrafo
   int 21h

   mov ah, 40h
   mov bx, 1
   mov cx, 22
   mov dx, color2msg
   int 21h

   mov ah, 3Fh
   mov bx, 0
   mov cx, 1
   mov dx, color2
   int 21h

   mov ah, 3Fh
   mov bx, 0
   mov cx, 2
   mov dx, crlf
   int 21h

   mov ah, 40h
   mov bx, 1
   mov cx, 1
   mov dx, paragrafo
   int 21h  

   sub [color1], 48
   sub [color2], 48  


   color1msg db "Defina a cor 1 (0-9): "   ;insert the color one 0-9
   color2msg db "Defina a cor 2 (0-9): "     
   paragrafo db 10 
   crlf rb 2 
   color1 rb 2
   color2 rb 2
```

but this only allows me to read from 0 to 9, can anyone help me puting this from 0 to 15 please?

Comment: why not use fn 0x0a for buffered input?

Comment: i'm not really worried with buffered input, i only really need someone to help me to read colors from 0 to 15

Comment: read from where? from file? i thought you want user to enter number 0 through 15

Comment: yes, but cause of ASCII table u cant read numbers higher then 10, u need to split them and multiply, but i dont know how to do it ..

Comment: Using DOS function 0x0A you read user input to a buffer. Specify buffer with length = 2. Then convert ASCII string with digits to number

Comment: but in ASCII only have from 0 to 9. How can u use double digits to colors? (video mode)

Comment: this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16987750/reading-a-two-digit-number-in-assembly-and-storing-it-in-a-variable

Comment: that is way to complex for my program. i got a simple program, i just need that mul or div :/

Comment: The file read (`ah = 3Fh`) knows how to read multiple bytes. Why don't you set `mov cx,2` and read two bytes, then convert the two byte ASCII to a two-digit number?

Comment: I'm sorry if this is blunt but if you feel that the suggestions are too complex for your program then I'm not sure you should be writing this program... :(

Comment: this is a project for university, altought we dont have alot of aknowledge about assembly..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could ask the user to input the hexadecimal digits A-F to represent the colors 10-15. This imposes the least changes to your program.
Change this

```
sub [color1], 48
sub [color2], 48
```

into

```
mov al,[color1]
cmp al,65
jbe tt1   ;0-9
sub al,7  ;A-F
tt1:
sub al,48
mov [color1],al

mov al,[color2]
cmp al,65
jbe tt2   ;0-9
sub al,7  ;A-F
tt2:
sub al,48
mov [color2],al
```

Also let the user know by changing the prompts.

```
color1msg db "Defina a cor 1 (0-9 A-F): "
color2msg db "Defina a cor 2 (0-9 A-F): "
```

Comment: That is very cleaver, thank you
However, i need to put into numbers 0-15, it is a project for university :(

Answer (score 2):

```
mov ah, 3Fh
mov bx, 0
mov cx, 2
mov dx, crlf
int 21h
```

To be able to respond to a 2-digit input you need a test to find out if the previous code did indeed get the bytes 13 and 10. I suggest the following

```
 ...
 mov ah, 3Fh
 mov bx, 0
 mov cx, 1
 mov dx, color1
 int 21h
 mov ah, 3Fh
 mov bx, 0
 mov cx, 2
 mov dx, crlf
 int 21h
 ; - - - - - - - - - -
 sub [color1],48
 mov ax, [crlf]
 cmp ax, 0A0Dh
 je OneDigit
TwoDigits:
 sub al, 48
 mov ah, [color1]
 aad             ; AL=AH*10+AL
 mov [color1], al
 mov ah, 3Fh     ; Fetch the still pending linefeed from DOS
 mov bx, 0
 mov cx, 1
 mov dx, crlf
 int 21h
OneDigit:
```

EDIT

The completed program follows. This should address the concerns expressed in the comments.

```
 mov ah, 40h
 mov bx, 1
 mov cx, 23
 mov dx, color1msg
 int 21h

 mov ah, 3Fh
 mov bx, 0
 mov cx, 1
 mov dx, color1
 int 21h

 mov ah, 3Fh
 mov bx, 0
 mov cx, 2
 mov dx, crlf
 int 21h

 sub BYTE [color1], 48
 mov al, BYTE [crlf]
 cmp al, 13
 je OneDigit_1
TwoDigits_1:
 sub al, 48
 mov ah, [color1]
 aad             ; AL=AH*10+AL
 mov [color1], al
 mov ah, 3Fh     ; Fetch the still pending linefeed from DOS
 mov bx, 0
 mov cx, 1
 mov dx, crlf
 int 21h
OneDigit_1:

 mov ah, 40h
 mov bx, 1
 mov cx, 1
 mov dx, paragrafo
 int 21h



 mov ah, 40h
 mov bx, 1
 mov cx, 23
 mov dx, color2msg
 int 21h

 mov ah, 3Fh
 mov bx, 0
 mov cx, 1
 mov dx, color2
 int 21h

 mov ah, 3Fh
 mov bx, 0
 mov cx, 2
 mov dx, crlf
 int 21h

 sub BYTE [color2], 48
 mov al, BYTE [crlf]
 cmp al, 13
 je OneDigit_2
TwoDigits_2:
 sub al, 48
 mov ah, [color2]
 aad             ; AL=AH*10+AL
 mov [color2], al
 mov ah, 3Fh     ; Fetch the still pending linefeed from DOS
 mov bx, 0
 mov cx, 1
 mov dx, crlf
 int 21h
OneDigit_2:

 mov ah, 40h
 mov bx, 1
 mov cx, 1
 mov dx, paragrafo
 int 21h  

 ...

 color1msg db "Defina a cor 1 (0-15): "
 color2msg db "Defina a cor 2 (0-15): "
 paragrafo db 10
 crlf rb 2
 color1 rb 1
 color2 rb 1
```

Comment: That does not work properly, it reads 1 or 2 digits yes, but the colors are wrong, if u put 15 it shows grey instead of WHITE

table of colors:
                 0 - BLACK
                 4 - RED
                 8 - DARKGRAY
12 - LIGHTRED
1 - BLUE
5 - MAGENTA
9 - LIGHTBLUE
13 - LIGHTMAGENTA
2 - GREEN
6 - BROWN
10 - LIGHTGREEN
14 - YELLOW
3 - CYAN
7 - LIGHTGRAY
11 - LIGHTCYAN
15 - WHITE

Comment: By using your code (copy paste it) i'm not able to run it this line mov ax,[crlf] gives me operand sizes do not match, if I change the ax to al or ah it does run but with the problem that Vasco Lopes described. Still unable to get this to work I also tryed change the cmp to ah or al I get value out of range

Comment: @PedroCavaleiro  I added a completed program to my answer. It works on my DOS and so it should address the concerns expressed in your comments.